# The inverse image of a projective map is a smooth variety.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f: \mathbb P^3 \to \mathbb P^2$ be a map from the projective 3-space to the projective plane given by $f(x,y,z,t)=(x^3+y^3+z^3+t^3,\; xy^2+zt^2,\; x^2z+y^2t)$.

We need to show that there is a non-empty open subset $V$ of $\mathbb P^2$ such that the inverse image $f^{-1}(a)$ is a smooth variety for all $a \in V$.

We also want to prove that there exists a non-empty open subset $W$ of $\mathbb P^2$ such that the function $h: W \to \mathbb N: a \mapsto deg(f^{-1}(a))$ is a constant function.

We have no idea how to start with this question.
Does someone know how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should note that $f$ is not defined on the common zero locus of $$ x^3+y^3+z^3+t^3,\; xy^2 + zt^2,\; x^2z + y^2t. $$
Call this common zero locus $V$.
Then you get a morphism by restricting $f$ to $\mathbb P^3 \setminus V$.
By restricting the codomain of $f$ you get a surjective morphism
$$g: \mathbb P^3 \setminus V \to f(\mathbb P^3 \setminus V).$$
Now your goal is to show that the family of varieties
$$ F = \{ g^{-1}(a) \mid a \in f(\mathbb P^3 \setminus V) \} $$
parametrized by $f(\mathbb P^3 \setminus V)$ is smooth in the generic case.
By the theorem of generic smoothness of families (this is discussed on p.93 of 'An invitation to algebraic geometry' for example) it follows that the members of $F$ which are smooth form an open subset of $F$.
So all you need to do is show that this subset is non-empty by finding one member that is smooth.
My guess is that you will want to consider a point $[a:b:c] \in f(\mathbb P^3 \setminus V)$ such that $a \ne 0$ to get a smooth inverse image under $g$.
Once you have found a suitable $[a:b:c]$ you can check smoothness of $g^{-1}[a:b:c]$ in the affine charts of $\mathbb P^3$.

Comment: Thank you, with a lot of computations I was able to prove that the point $[2:1:1]$ is a point such that $g^{-1}[a:b:c]$ is smooth in the affine charts!

Answer (score 0):

Over $\mathbb{C}$ there is no non-constant morphism  $f: \mathbb{CP}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{CP}^2$. To see this, then assume it exists, note that the pull back of the hyperplane class $f^{*}(H) \in H^{2}(\mathbb{CP}^3,\mathbb{Z})$ is non-zero (by the assumption that the morphism is non-constant). But then $$f^{*}(H)^3 = f^*(H^3)= f^*(0)=0.$$

But, there is no non-zero element in $H^{2}(\mathbb{CP}^3,\mathbb{Z})$ that cubes to zero. (for this one may consult the standard presentation of the cohomology ring of projective space, which is well-known)